# Displaying my Program Name in setup security prompt

Tags: c#, windows, installation, code-signing, setup-deployment

I use VS2010 to create a setup and deployment Project. I want to set the Program name. I have tried using the Properties window and set the Manufacturer Name and Title but when the 'Do you trust this Application' Dialog Shows during setup process, It shows the Installation Path instead of the name.

```
Program Name : C:/Users/C-SHARP/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Matrix/MatrixSetup/Setup.exe  
Publisher : Unknown  
Source : Hard disk on the Computer.
```

What I want is that the "Program Name" should show `Matrix` instead of the Path. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security prompt, designed to protect users from unsafe applications that might compromise their machine.

The only way to change what is displayed in that message (and/or prevent it from being displayed altogether) is to obtain a signed certificate for your installer and application, which proves that you're a legitimate vendor with a legitimate executable.

Once you've obtained your certificate from a trusted authority like [VeriSign](https://www.symantec.com/products-solutions/families/?fid=code-signing) or [Comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/), you will need to use [`signtool.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx) to sign both your application and installer. You can either use SignTool's GUI mode, or integrate it into your build process as a command line application.

Microsoft maintains a help page on code signing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361.aspx). Another good online resource is [here](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought).